# Justdoing some data structures examples

Tags: c

question -: Suppose a company keeps a linear array YEAR(1950:1960) such that YEAR[K]contains no of babies born in  year K. Write a program to  perform following tasks.
a. To print each year in which no baby was born.
b. To find number of years in which no baby was born

MY Answer:-

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int year[10],k,count=0;
    printf("Enter the elements of the array from 1950 to 1960\n");
    for(k=1950;k<1960;k++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&year[k]);
    }
    printf("Entered values of the year from 1950 to 1960 are\n");
    for(k=1950;k<1960;k++)
    {
        if(year[k]==0)
        {
            printf("%d"" year have number of babies born %d\n",k,year[k]);
            count = count+1;
        }
    }
    printf("Total number of year where no baby born is %d\n",count);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKzm4.png)

I DUNNO WHY IT AINT WORKING PLS HELP

Comment: what is the meaning of "AINT WORKING" ?

Comment: it doesnt take input

Comment: Your `year` array is index-capable from 0..9. You're indexing from 1950..1959. that's obviously a problem. Your code invokes *undefined behavior*. Even if that is fixed, the following loop is still broken, both in indexing *and* in logic. Besides the broken indexing (again), you only print if `if(year[k]==0)` is *true*. Therefore, the output, if anything does print, will *always* state zero babies.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information. What exactly means "it doesnt take input"? Does it not stop to let you enter the numbers? Does it not store the values? Please describe exactly what you do, what input you use, what happens or what output you get and what you would expect.

Comment: You have **undefined behavior** in your program because you're accessing elements that are out of bounds of the array `year`.

Comment: @WhozCraig yea mate sry for my by dumb mistake

Answer (score 1):

Index 0 will equal 1950 and index 9 will equal 1960, so you shouldn't use the actual numbers of the years in your code, since your code and the array with 10 items is an abstraction of them.

- Change your loops to `for(k=0;k<10;k++)`.
- When printing this internal, abstract representation to something meaningful for the user, you should `printf("%d", k+1950)`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set num=0
2. Repeat for k=1920to1970

   ```
     if A[K]=15
   ```
3. Set num=Num+1

4)Exit

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).